# How to sign android apk using jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, apk, keystore, signing

I have my keystore `release.keystore` in the path `/home/ankit/keystores/release.keystore`. I want to use the keypair aliased as `example` for signing an app that is built using Jenkins. However, I am unable to feed the address of the keystore in the Jenkins. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

As it can be seen, there is a drop down list against the key store label and it has no item. I tried to follow the official doc but I didn't get it.

I think I have to link the existing keypair somehow to Jenkins, so that it shows up in the drop down list. But I can't figure how.

Comment: *if you can't help me, restraint yourself from clicking that duplicate/downvote button.* => you completely misunderstand, there is no relation between knowing the answer and evaluating the question as bad or dupe. More reading on this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question).

Comment: Please do not offer voting advice in your posts. If anything, that is a downvote magnet in itself.

Answer (score 4):

Instead you could configure this all in gradle itself, which will work independent of any CI. First create a `build.properties` in root of your project and include following:

```
#Key store
keystore.release=../keys/release.keystore
keystore.debug=../keys/debug.keystore
keystore.key.alias=...
keystore.key.password=...
keystore.password=...
```

Now in your app modules `build.gradle` access those props:

```
final Properties props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream('build.properties'))
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias props['keystore.key.alias']
            keyPassword props['keystore.key.password']
            storeFile file(props['keystore.release'])
            storePassword props['keystore.password']
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file(props['keystore.debug'])
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

Now make sure it works in your local machine with `./gradlew clean assembleRelease` (There's something else if you do in PC)

After that commit the changes and update the gradle build settings in your CI. And make sure those keystores are there.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. However, its better if keystore passwords and aliases are not hardcoded into gradle file. I found this article helpful too: https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/

Comment: @AnkitShubham yes you are right, you can instead read it from some where else.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Android Signing Jenkins Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/android-signing-plugin#usage) documentation:

> Before adding a Sign Android APKs build step to a job, you must configure a certificate credential using the Credentials Plugin's UI.

If you need more details about how to use the Credentials Plugin in Jenkins, [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc) is the user guide.